# How to gain access to WHM (CPanel)?

Tags: linux, ssh, apache-http-server, wordpress, cpanel

I have started on a new project and need to access the WHM and cPanel. I have tried to log into the server through SSH (denied). I then used the terminal on cPanel to run some commands and get permission denied in the www/html folder.

When I try to access WHM by the port number (2087) I do not get any page response. Same happens when I use thesite.com/whm.

What is causing this and what do I need from the previous developer to fix it?

Comment: How about asking the previous developer: "How can I access the WHM and Cpanel, if they are in fact there?

Comment: They are not there, I have tried to call her but cant get through

Comment: Then learn the lesson: if you are not given the access you need, you cannot do your job, and do something else, and blame it on them. You tried, no access, not your fault.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can also contact the host provider directly to get the access you require.

Answer (score -2):

First of all, if your Server's IP Address is x.x.x.x use https before it,

```
https://x.x.x.x:2087
```

Otherwise, you'll redirected to Hostname like https://hostname:2087.

Comment: This is not given and and depends entirely on the server configuration.